# Is it possible to set Zend_Date options in application.ini config?

Tags: php, zend-framework, app-config, zend-date

Is it possible to set Zend_Date options in application.ini config like this:

```
resources.date.options.format_type = php
```

in Zend Framework v 1.* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default such resource it not available: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

However, nothing stops you from creating your own resource:

1.In `application.ini` specify resource path & date settings

```
pluginPaths.My_Application_Resource = "My/Application/Resource"
resources.date.options.format_type = "php"
```

2.Creating resource

```
<?php
class My_Application_Resource_Date extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        Zend_Date::setOptions($options['options']);
    }    
}
```